# BIP Report rft template fix

Tags: bi-publisher

I have a BIP report rft file in which the layout of the table needs to be updated. Currently, the data is being displayed correctly but the formatting is not correct. I am trying to adjust the template but due to lack of experience I am not able to meet the requirement.
This is the existing/current output:
[image]

And this is the template that is required:
[image]

Major issues i am having is:

1. Unable to adjust height of the rows
2. Unable to adjust row spacing

The RTF file is [here](https://file.town/download/80mjasxaafxgs1itgnwc5psub)
The sample xml is [here](https://file.town/download/o2vk5o0z5c7546eyg6dawy9r8)

Comment: Google chrome blocked the download of your .rtf file, says it contains malicious content. I cant understand why a .rtf template would be 7 mb, so I trust Google.

Comment: this time google is wrong :)

Comment: Why is the rtf file 7 MB?

Comment: I don;t know sir. Download and find out.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the template into a new fresh document, and then re-upload to a different site? There's no reason an rtf file should be 7 MB, unless you have some large graphics in it, which you shouldn't, can can remove for uploading purposes. Upload XML to a different site too. It's possible that the site is injecting malicious code. You can try pastebin.com for uploading XML as pure text.

Comment: I copy pasted to another file and as you said the size is now 14.6kb approx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily adjust row height and column width with Microsoft Word.

Comment: Sir unable to do it as i mentioned 02 things that I am unable to achieve.

Comment: Especially I am not sure how to adjust space among rows.

Comment: Are you using Word? If so, why can't you adjust the rows/columns?

Comment: I am trying. The columns are adjusted but the row spacing is giving problems as in the To Be template the law row does not have any space but i am getting one.

Comment: Can you re-share the template?

Comment: I did. Its size is around 15kb now. You want me to share it again?

Comment: Ya, but find a different place to host it.